# A billinear transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$w(z)=(az+b)/(cz+d)$$.Then $w(z)$ maps a straight line of $z-$plane to the circle $|w|=1$ in $w-$plane if

$1.|b|=|d|$

$2. |a|=|c|$

$3. |a|=|d|$

$4. |b|=|c|$

**My work**: I started by considering *Im(z)=0* which gives an equation of a circle in *w-plane* provided some restrictions on the coefficients are satisfied. I obtained the restrictions but however, unable to reach any option given in question.I do not think that a MCQ has such a lengthy solution. There must be something I am completely missing.
Kindly help me or give any hint to solve this.

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: $w$ is not bilinear, by the way. A function needs to have two arguments to be bilinear. It's not linear in $z$, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|w|=1\Rightarrow |az+b|=|cz+d|\Rightarrow|a||z+\frac ba|=|c||z+\frac dc|$

This is a straight line iff $|a|=|c|$, namely the perpendicular bisector of $-\frac ba$ and $-\frac dc$.

When $|a|\neq|c|$, the locus of $z$ is a Circle of Apollonius.

Comment: Thanks..David Quinn..I understand now.